# Why would a VirtualBox VM not be accessible from a computer on the LAN using the same physical NIC?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a VM and a computer on my LAN. Both used addresses of the form 192.168.2.x and they could connect without a problem as the VM is setup with Bridged Network.

Now I added a new NIC to avoid [an issue with broadcasting packets](https://superuser.com/questions/1632104). I switched both computers to addresses 10.0.2.x instead (so a brand new network).

I can perfectly access the two computers from the Host computer, but, somehow, the two computers do not communicate with each others.

Just in case, I turned off the firewalls on both the VM and that LAN machine. I can't just turn off the Host firewall, but since it is a distinct network, I don't have rules to prevent connections on that NIC.

Here is a simple graph showing the network setup:

```
+------------+
| Host       |
|            |
| +--------+ |
| | VM     | |
| |        | |
| +---+----+ |
|     |      |     +----------+
|     v      |     | LAN      |
|    NIC <---------| Computer |
|            |     |          |
+------------+     +----------+
```

I can also get the VM and LAN computers to connect to the Internet with a `MASQUERADE` rule in my Host firewall (I tried with and without the rule to make sure it would not be what prevents the connections between the VM and LAN computers). `ping Host` from the VM and LAN works. `ping VM` and `ping LAN` from the Host works. The VM is setup with a Bridged Network.

When I try `ssh` between the two computers, I get the error:

> No route to host

I can `ssh` from the Host to the VM and the LAN computers just fine.

I also tried a `traceroute` from the VM. It stops on the VM?! wouldn't the host know how to forward the packets properly?

```
$ traceroute 10.0.2.21
traceroute to 10.0.2.21 (10.0.2.21), 64 hops max
  1   10.0.2.1  1441.960ms !H  *  57.390ms !H
```

Yet the route looks proper to me:

```
$ ip route show
default via 10.0.2.10 dev enp0s8 proto static 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.1
```

**NOTE:** I tried without and also with a 10/100 switch. Either way, the LAN computer works just fine with the Host.

---

**Update:**

As I posted on the VirtualBox forum, I was asked to test with Wireshark. The one main thing I discovered is that the IP address is being discovered using ARP messages and the VM and LAN computers both receive the messages. I can see the MAC address being shared, but the VM never receives anything. The LAN computer receives the VM MAC address but the ping itself is never going anywhere.

I'm not too sure whether that helps, but that means the hardware & software are both capable of sending data over the physical and virtual wires. It's still blocked in some way, though.

Comment: You could ask here as well: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewforum.php?f=7

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the pointer. I posted a copy [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=102126)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov No luck so far...

Comment: What kind of interface did you use in VirtualBox for your VM?

Comment: @MathiasWeidner The interface is a USB based cabled Ethernet port (a Sabrent based on a Realtek chip; I use this driver: `sabrent-nt-s25g-driver`). At first I directly connected that port to the LAN computer, and then I tried going through an old switch, but either way did not help the VM. `ssh` between the Host and LAN work just fine either way so I would think the port itself works as expected.

Comment: I was asking for the [networking mode](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes) in VirtualBox.

Comment: @MathiasWeidner Ah, okay. It's using the Bridged Network mode. I updated my question to include the info. I did not change that when switching between the 192.168.2.x and the 10.0.2.x. What changed is the interface.

Comment: OK. Since your on the same network, you would at first look for the ARP packets at the endpoints. Make a PING from the VM to the LAN computer and look with tcpdump or wireshark on the LAN computer for ARP requests and answers. Then make a PING from the LAN computer to the VM and look at the VM for ARP requests and answers. Do you see both at both sides?

Comment: @MathiasWeidner I'm not used to ARP, but I tested that and I can see a discrepancy. The LAN computer gets a reply and then tries to use the MAC address but the `ping` still fails. The VM, however, never gets the ARP reply. I can see that the LAN computer receives the ARP message and generates the response, but it looks like it gets lost on the way back. I'll upload those Wireshark logs on the VirtualBox forum some time tomorrow.

Comment: Then something is preventing the ARP requests to cross the bridge VirtualBox has set up for your VM. Maybe you want to post your findings at the VirtualBox forum too.